# Fancybox Opens On Pageload, But No Longer Modal

Tags: fancybox, launch

I am attempting to use a document ready function I found on your site to force a fancybox lightbox to appear when a page loads.  Here is the code I am using, (I found it here on your site). It does force the fancybox to appear on page load, but it forces it to open in a new page and it loses it's modal properties when I add in the $document ready function.

I'm not terribly technical, but after hours of researching and trying several methods, I'm giving and seeking help. Any support would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css" />
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fancybox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sameheight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a name="hidden_link" id="hidden_link"  a class="lightbox" href="#popup01"></a>
</div>
<div class="popup-holder">
    <div id="popup01" class="lb">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you may missed to include css or js files for fancybox.

Comment: Sorry they are there above the document ready function. I just edited the post to show what's above the body.

Comment: After I added the Document Ready Function, I added in the hidden anchor here <a name="hidden_link" id="hidden_link"  a class="lightbox" href="#popup01"></a>and this is when the modal seemed to stop working. The fancybox will appear automatically now, but it's no longer modal and opens in a new page instead of on top of the existing page.